# localization in Chrome extensions

Tags: javascript, html, internationalization, google-chrome-extension

I have a query related to localization of Chrome extensions. I am trying to localize the text in a button in a popup html file in my extension. The code I am using is as follows:

```
<button name="buttonSave" id="buttonSave" style="width: 100px; float: right;">
       <label class="buttonTextStyle">

       </label>
</button>
```

The javascript code is as follows:

```
document.getElementById("buttonSave").innerText = chrome.i18n.getMessage("SaveButton");
```

I have tried using innerText, innerHTML, value but the text in the button is not applied. Am I doing something wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would just use `<input type="button">` and set the `value` property of the button:

```
<input type="button" name="buttonSave" id="buttonSave" style="width: 100px; float: right;">

....

document.getElementById("buttonSave").value = chrome.i18n.getMessage("SaveButton");
```

By the way, I'm fairly certain having a `<label>` nested inside of a `<button>` is not valid HTML.  Use a `<div>` or `<span>` instead.

**EDIT**:

I just did a test, and using either `.innerHTML` or `.innerText` should work fine.  Are you sure that:

1. the return value of `chrome.i18n.getMessage("SaveButton")` is non-empty?
2. you are running `document.getElementById("buttonSave")` after the DOM is built (i.e., `document.getElementById("buttonSave")` is not null or throwing an error)?

Also, understand that overwriting the `innerText` or `innerHTML` of the button will destroy the elements you have inside the button already.  Perhaps you actually want to do `document.querySelector("#buttonSave .buttonTextStyle").innerText` to write the the element nested inside the button?

Comment: Thanks. :) `document.querySelector("#buttonSave .buttonTextStyle").innerText` did the trick.