# Modify button text with chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

How can you modify the text of a button of a specific website to something else, with the development of a google chrome extension ?

Comment: What is your current progress with the extension? If you haven't even started yet, here is the official tutorial: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/getstarted

Comment: I can't find the part of code that I need to add to modify the text of an html element of my choice that shows in the page.

Comment: The code you need to add to your content script should be something like this: document.getElementById(button_id).innerHTML = 'NewName';

Comment: Solution given in this SO post - [localization in Chrome extensions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11612355/localization-in-chrome-extensions) might just be what you need.

Comment: At the bottom of Granga's link is the [Chrome Extension Overview](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/overview).  That page says "If your extension needs to interact with web pages, then it needs a content script."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provided that you otherwise know how to create a chrome extension, it depends on whether you have a *button* element or an *input* element. If the target website contains:

```
<button id="myButton" type="button" value=""></button>
<input id="myInputButton" type="button" value=""></button>
```

Then your content script can change the button texts like so:

```
document.getElementById('myButton').innerHTML = "something else";
document.getElementById('myInputButton').value = "something else";
```